# Why would 'go build file.go' work fine at my local terminal, but give me an error over SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, go

When I run 'go build file.go' (or 'go install') at my local terminal (Konsole on ubuntu), my code builds correctly without any warnings. However, when I SSH (from another linux box or using PuTTY from Windows) into the exact same machine, I get the warning messages:

> warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home/[username]/go) has no effect go
>   build runtime: linux/amd64 must be bootstrapped using make.bash

In terminal:
'go version' reports go1.3.3 linux/amd64
'which go' reports /usr/local/go/bin/go
Over SSH:
'go version' reports go1.2.1 linux/amd64
'which go' reports /home/[username]/go/bin/go

Comment: Where are you setting your go environment variables? `.bashrc`? `.bash_login`? `.profile`? Desktop environment startup?

Comment: Fixed: I usually use .bashrc for environment variables, but for some reason I had modified .bash_profile to change the path for go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly your environment is different between your local (presumably GUI desktop) Ubuntu logon and your ssh logon.

This isn't unexpected.

SUGGESTION:

1) Type "env" from your local Konsole GUI terminal.  Make note of the environment variables that are particularly important to you: PATH, GOPATH, GOROOT, etc.

2) Edit your `$HOME/.profile` file (aka `~/.profile`).

Explicitly set those variables.

3) Try ssh again - see if there's any difference.

See also:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101168/set-environment-variable-automatically-upon-ssh-login-no-root-access

You might also consider enabling remote VNC:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-vnc-for-ubuntu-12

https://askubuntu.com/questions/304017/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-sharing-through-ssh